# ERROR is "group function is nested too deeply"?

Tags: mysql, min

tried to display the name of the department that has the least student count.

Comment: Your query is nonsensical. So see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query instead

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 department_name, count(*) AS number_of_students
FROM department natural join student
GROUP BY department_name
ORDER BY number_of_students
```

It will give you the list of departments ordered by the number of students. By selecting only the first row via `TOP 1` you will only get the department with the least number of students.

Comment: only has to show department_name and can have multiple rows with same minimum value.

Comment: TOP is MSSQL syntax and not MySQL syntax so your answer is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Is it like this way?

```
SELECT 
T1.department_name, COUNT(T2.department_id) totalCount
FROM department T1
LEFT JOIN student T2
ON T1.department_id = T2.department_id
GROUP BY T2.department_id
HAVING COUNT(T2.department_id) =
(
  SELECT  
  COUNT(T2.department_id) totalCount
  FROM department T1
  LEFT JOIN student T2
  ON T1.department_id = T2.department_id
  GROUP BY T2.department_id
  ORDER BY totalCount ASC
  LIMIT 1
)
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9ba2e/2)